# Can I Use 4" CPVC Pipe for a Dryer vent?

Tags: vent, dryer

Can I use 4" CPVC pipe to extend a dryer vent in my garage?

Answer (score 8):

No. It has to be rigid metal pipe in the wall. Plastic pipe is a fire hazard.

Note that you cannot use screws to attach together metal pipe for dryer vents; lint can collect on it and become a fire hazard.

Comment: I upvoted anyway, but this answer could be even better if you explained the proper way to attach the pieces of metal pipe together.

Comment: Use an Aluminum Foil Tape like 3M Scotch 3311. Be aware that the adhesive is very tenacious. The pipe must be clean and the tape will not be movable once the adhesive sticks. Get it on straight without folds. Once stuck to itself, you **will not** get it apart. To pull joints apart, use a craft knife to slice the seam.